# Efficiently draw multiple opengl elements

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d

I'm currently learning opengl and started to make  my own 2D engine. So far I've managed to render an rectangle made out of 2 triangles with `glDrawElements()` and apply it a custom shader.

This is how my code looks like so far:

```
#include <all>

int main() {
    Window window("OpenGL", 800, 600);
    Shader shader1("./file.shader");

    float vt[8] = {-0.5f, -0.5f,    0.5f, -0.5f,     0.5f, 0.5f,    -0.5f, 0.5f };
    const GLuint indices[6] = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0 };

    GLuint vao, vbo, ebo;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vt), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    while(window.isOpen()) {
        window.clear(0.0, 0.5, 1.0);

        shader1.use();
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);

        window.update();
    }

    /* glDeleteStuffs */
}
```

There multiple way to do it, but I've heard that drawing and switching shaders one by one is pretty expensive. I'm looking to preload all the data, vertices, shaders in one buffer or what's more efficient and when it's all ready start drawing them in one call, similar to a batch. Thanks!

Comment: If the GPU has enough memory for all shaders, buffers, textures, FBOs, etc, then don't be afraid of using hundreds (or even thousands) of draw-calls. If not, that's another story, which depends on what you want to update to GPU RAM. Also, setting another context as current or doing some changes to the current one is not cheap.